# json parsing with asp Xtreme using array

Tags: json, asp-classic

So what I am trying to have is the following parsed json.
Instead, I am getting  `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Data'`  the error.
I am sure that the error is not with getting the data from the database, it works fine when I dont try to parse it.
PS: I am suing asp extreme's plugin here.

```
    {
        "checkins": {
            "data": [
            {   
                "strFirstName": "james",
                "strDateEntered": "2013-03-01 15:13:49"
            },
            {   
                "strFirstName": "john",
                "strDateEntered": "2013-03-05 15:13:49"
            }
    ]
    }
}
```

codes:

```
Set Dataset = JSON.parse("{}")
Dataset.set "checkins", JSON.parse("{ ""data"": [] }")

SQL = "SELECT C.CheckinID, C.MemberID, C.VENUENAME, C.VenueLat, C.VenueLng, C.VENUECREATEDAT, C.CheckInDateEntered"
SQL = SQL & " FROM CHECKINS C"
SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY VENUECREATEDAT DESC" 
Set objCheckins = objConn.Execute(SQL)


If NOT objCheckins.EOF Then 
    Do While NOT objCheckins.EOF

        SQL = "SELECT FirstName, LastName"
        SQL = SQL & " FROM MEMBERS"
        Set objMember = objConn.Execute(SQL)

        Set Record = JSON.parse("{}")
            Record.set "strFirstName", ""& objMember("FirstName") & ""
            Record.set "strDateEntered", ""& objCheckins("VENUECREATEDAT") & ""
            Dataset.data.push(Record)
        Set Record = nothing

        Data = JSON.stringify(Dataset, null, 2)

    objCheckins.Movenext 
    Loop

End If
objCheckins.Close
Set objCheckins = Nothing

Response.Write Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this "plugin": [Asp Extreme Evolution](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json.asp)?

If you look at the examples they give, you should probably use

```
Record.setElement "..field..", "..value.."
```

Also, the `Set Record = JSON(...` and `Set Record = Nothing` should be moved before and after the ObjCheckings loop, respectively.

If you use something else, please let us know what plugin exactly.